# Why am I getting a 404 error with my Laravel AJAX POST request?

Tags: ajax, laravel, post, request, http-status-code-404

When I try to send an ajay post request to projects/delete, I get POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects/delete 404 (Not Found) error.

My ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '/projects/delete',
         data: {
         _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
         id: id
         },
         success: function(){
            thisBtn.closest('tr').fadeOut();
         },
         error: function(){
            alert('Nem sikerült a törlés!');
         }
});
```

My Route:

`Route::post('/projects/delete', 'TesztController@deleteProject');`

My Controller:

```
public function deleteProject(Request $request)
{
   $project = Project::find($request->input('id'));
   $project->delete();

   return "ok";
}
```

Comment: make sure you routes are not cached first (which there is no need for them to be in development) `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: You are using the old syntax for referencing controllers. If you have a new project created from scratch it will not work. Take a look at [routing](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing) for how to reference the controller method in newer projects

Comment: Thanks both of you! I cleared the cache and replaced the old controller syntax to the new and now it's working.

Comment: And use delete request, follow REST rules,  you are in 2023, not in 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all change your route like this

```
Route::post('/projects/delete', [TesztController::class,deleteProject]);
```

then run this command to clear all the caches

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```